# Confusion about corollary 6.11 in Chapter I in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Corollary 6.11 in Hartshorne:

Every curve is birationally equivalent to a nonsingular projective curve.

And its proof said that any curve with function field $K$ is birationaly equivalent to a set of regular local ring $C_{k}$. But the question is, only the nonsingular point would be birationally equivalent to a regular local ring. What if a curve contains singular points? Does it still biratinally equivalent to a nonsingular projective curve?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant "What if a curve contains *singular* points?" A rational map is only defined on an open subset, so we can take the open subset to be the complement of the singular points.

Comment: Ok, I will try to understand that. Thanks!